# How to animate a line that is drawn using Line Renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am drawing a path using Line Renderer. Currently I apply a material to the line renderer and it's working great, the only problem now is, that I want that path to be animated. The path is actually a water current and I need it animated so it'll show water current motion. Below are some screenshots.

[image: path drawn with finger using line renderer]

[image: line renderer component with material "LineMat"]

[image: here's my LineMat material]

So how can I animate this material or is there any other solution to achieve this behaviour.

**P.S.**

The path is drawn using `Input.GetMouseButton` in `Update` by user when the game startd.

Comment: You should code with shader to animate LineRenderer, if you don't know how to do animation find it out on assetStore as beginning point how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please provide me some link from where I can start this.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate UV coordinate offset in the material - this have an effect of the texture moving along the path

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTextureOffset.html

```
public Material material;
public Vector2 offsetSpeed=Vector2.one;

void Update()
{
   material.mainTextureOffset+=offsetSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you please explain more, how can I change UV coordinate offset of material ?

Comment: by using mainTextureOffset setter, updated the answer to include a link